# strange character from a jewish shoutcast

Tags: php, html, jquery, hebrew, shoutcast

i'm retrieving a current song of a shoutcast with a php script for displaying it in html5 wordpress template, like that :

```
$shoutcast_url = $_POST["url"];

$e = explode("/",$shoutcast_url);
$shoutcast_url = $e[0]."//".$e[2]."/";

$context = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($context, 'http', 'header', 'user-agent: Mozilla');

libxml_set_streams_context($context);
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$load = $doc->loadHTMLFile($shoutcast_url);

if($load)
{
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
    $query = $xpath->query('//td[contains(., "Current Song")]/../td[position() = last()]');

    $song = $query->item(0)->nodeValue;
    echo $song;
}
else
{
    echo 'serveur down';
}
```

but the song title is like that : éåñó îùä ëäðà - æëø ãáø ìòáãê

i would like to display it normally and even if i change the html tag like that

```
<html dir="rtl" lang="he">
```

and add in the head the meta

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
```

it still display éåñó îùä ëäðà - æëø ãáø ìòáãê. i tried the utf8_encode function but it return black diamond shape with a interrogation mark.

Hope you can help :/

Comment: Can you post the actual HTML you are parsing?  As far as I know, SHOUTcast metadata doesn't not completely support non-ASCII encodings, but some players and software do.  The data on the page itself might be broken, and some additional massaging of the data may be necessary.

Comment: Jewish shout cast? how offensive is that.